# Force RecyclerView to redraw its items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, redraw

Is there any way to redraw all items of `RecyclerView`?

I have some Themes (in style.xml) and after changing the theme, I need the `RecyclerView` to be redrawn.

So I want a method that will force to re-call `onCreateViewHolder` for each items of the adapter.

I tried to:

- call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged` but `onCreateViewHolder` is not called
- call `recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE)` and then `recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`
- call `recyclerView.invalidate()`
- call `recyclerView.setAdapter(null)` and then `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)`.
  This works well for 90% items. Only 90% of items will get the new style, but some items will have the old style

I mention that the `RecyclerView` is attached to an Activity, not to a Fragment.

Comment: Make sure you call notifyDataSetChanged() from the UI thread, it should work.

Comment: @Nanoc notifyDataSetChanged only force onBindNewHolder, not onCreate

Comment: Sorry, im not familiarized with the viewHolder pattern but i will say that you should adapt your code to work with it (or dont use it).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I found the answer!
The correct way to do this is:

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(null);
recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(myLayoutManager);
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

After that, all the items are getting the new style!

Comment: `adapter.doYourStaff();recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);` This 2 lines of code is enough!

Comment: recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter) is enough for me.

Comment: This worked for me too except I didn't need the first two lines (i.e. null assignments).

Comment: I checked recyclerView and myAdapter for not being null before applying and works fine

Answer (score 30):

Simply setting recyclerview's adapter again worked for me (I wanted RecyclerView to redraw all items' layout again)

```
/**
 * Forces RecyclerView adapter to call createViewHolder() - i.e. redraw all all items' layouts
 */
private fun resetAdapterState() {
    val myAdapter = recyclerView.adapter
    recyclerView.adapter = myAdapter
}
```

Comment: Or, for Java `RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = myRecyclerView.getAdapter();
        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: Probably the best answer :)

Comment: I would add `recyclerView.adapter = null` before `recyclerView.adapter = myAdapter` to call `onDetachedFromRecyclerView()` on adapter automaticlly

Comment: Thanks. For me, only working answer. I changed code to recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerView.getAdapter()); Or, more simply, set Adapter again: recyclerView.setAdapter(mMyAdapter);

Answer (score 12):

If you want to force redraw, you need clear View Pool of `RecycleView`. You can use `recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().clear();`

Comment: ViewHolders still not re-drawn after i call clear. Even if i call notifyDataSetChanged. Somehow still cached viewholders are re-used..

Answer (score 8):

The below lines of code did the trick for me

```
recyclerview.swapAdapter(myAdapter,false);
recyclerview.setLayoutManager(myLayoutManager);
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 8):

Resetting the Adapter worked for me, I called this inside `onConfigChange`

```
myRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter)
```

Comment: This answer worked for me when I needed to remove selections after exiting a multi-selection mode.  I notified the related fragment through an interface method, inside of which I reset the adapter as this answer suggests.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is old, but I had a situation where I needed to change the viewholder types after `notifyDataSetChanged()`.  If the adapter already had data, `onCreateViewHolder` was not being called because of the "recycle" part of recycleviewadapter, so a type cast error was being thrown in `onBindViewHolder`.

I was able to solve this by calling `myRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().removeAllViews();` before calling `notifyDataSetChanged();` on the adapter.

Answer (score 4):

The only solution that worked for me on an Amazon Fire HD was this:

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(null);
recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().clear();
recyclerView.swapAdapter(myAdapter, false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33342314/4142087

Shortly, you can create different types of view holders, changing view type will force RecyclerView to pass another `ViewHolder` to the `onBindViewHolder`.

If you use `setTheme`, you have to recreate whole Activity like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14367214/4142087

Comment: If thats how this shoud be done that viewholder pattern doesnt look as the cleanest.

Comment: @DenisCovaci Try to save data in the instance state and recreate activity

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
recyclerView.adapter = recyclerView.adapter
recyclerView.post {
    recyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

It shows blank if running without `post{}`

Comment: Doing recyclerView.adapter = recyclerView.adapter without notifyDataSetChanged() worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Redraw the Recycler again Kotlin:

```kotlin
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
                   delay(3000L)
                   binding.recyclerView.adapter.also {
                       binding.recyclerView.adapter = null
                       binding.recyclerView.adapter = it
                   }
```

Comment: Please read "[answer]" and "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Answer (score 0):

Force RecyclerView to onCreateViewHolder or redraw its items #Kotlin

This worked for me

```
        this.runOnUiThread {
            val adapter = recyclerView.adapter
            val layoutManager = recyclerView.layoutManager
            recyclerView.adapter = null
            recyclerView.layoutManager = null
            recyclerView.adapter = adapter
            recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
            adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
```

hope this can help

Comment: You should add that this case works for code execution (callback method) from background. Reason your code would not work is for callback being executed in different thread then main.

Answer (score 0):

After trying most of the ideas here - if turns out that my issue was down to using a simulator.  When testing on devices I've had no issues with this.