# How to fix:'notifyDataSetChanged() not updating the ImageView in RecyclerView Adapter'

Tags: android, android-layout, android-adapter, android-adapterview

Suppose I have a recyclerView Adapter which is used to populate views including imageView . When i first load adapter then recycler view items are getting displayed properly . But if i update imageView and textview resource in adapter datasource and call notifyDataSetChanged() method then only textview is getting updated and not imageView . Can anyone help me with this ? Thanks in advance .

For Example - This is the first time i add all the elements in an empty arraylist inside fragment and update using notifyDataSetChanged() method . Till now everything is fine and images are loading correctly in adapter .

Below is the getMethod()

```
                    if(remindersListResponse.code == 200)
                    {
                        if(remindersListResponse.data != null)
                        {
                            photoContactList.clear();

                           photoContactList.addAll(remindersListResponse.data);
                            photoContactsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

                    }
```

Now if i call getMethod again on click of some button in fragment and use notifyDataSetChanged() method . Then only text gets updated in adapter items but not images instead they get disappear .

This is my adapter onBindViewHolder(...) method

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        final PhotoContactsResponse.Result photoContactDetail = photoContactList.get(i);

        viewHolder.photoContactName.setText(photoContactDetail.name);

        if(photoContactDetail.image!=null && !photoContactDetail.image.isEmpty()) {
            viewHolder.addPhotoText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(Constants.WEB_SERVICE_BASE_URL_FOR_IMAGE+photoContactDetail.image)
                    .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                    .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                    .into(viewHolder.photoContactImage);
        }
        else
        {
            viewHolder.addPhotoText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewHolder.photoContactImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
}
```

This is my model class

```
public static class Result{
        public int id;
        public String name;
        public String number;
        public String image;
        public int index;
    }
```

Comment: Can you edit your post and add some relevant code ? like adapter for example.
and please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: share your code for better understanding

Comment: are you populating image from drawable or from server url in imageView?

Comment: @MiteshMachhoya i have checked for both i.e. drawable as well as server url .

Comment: can you please show your code and sample data

Comment: @Rishabh:  did you debug and check whether your method is being called or not?

Comment: @KaranMer Yes i have debug the code and method is called and proof is textviews are getting updated in adapter items .

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this same issue and fixed it by setting the recycle view's adapter to null, then to my adapter again. See: [Force RecyclerView to redraw its items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36495009/force-recyclerview-to-redraw-its-items)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I wouldn't recommend this approach, this is just a workaround that doesn't fix the OP's mistake. I think the answer a couple of years ago gives a working solution even though the OP didn't accept it.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the info. I am admittedly new to android development so I was just happy to get it working

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to set ImageView as VISIBLE. When you hide it in `else` statement you should always bring it back when image is available. `onBindViewHolder` only binds data to view. Recycler views are reused between calls to `onBindViewHolder` method.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        final PhotoContactsResponse.Result photoContactDetail = photoContactList.get(i);

        viewHolder.photoContactName.setText(photoContactDetail.name);

        if(photoContactDetail.image!=null && !photoContactDetail.image.isEmpty()) {
            viewHolder.addPhotoText.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
            viewHolder.photoContactImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // <== ADD THIS LINE

            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(Constants.WEB_SERVICE_BASE_URL_FOR_IMAGE+photoContactDetail.image)
                    .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                    .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                    .into(viewHolder.photoContactImage);
        }
        else
        {
            viewHolder.addPhotoText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewHolder.photoContactImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
}
```