# Rows in GridLayoutManager expand but do not shrink when item content changes

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I have a RecyclerView with a GridLayoutManager.
Every item has a button and a invisible content.
When the user presses the button, the content switches its visibility.

When the content is invisible and the user press the button for the first time, the item expands, and so do the other items on the same row

[image: Status before pressing any button]

[image: Status after pressing a button]

The problem arises after the user presses again the button: the row doesn't shrink

[image: The row doesn't shrink]

The same happens for every row

[image: Status after pressing the button again]

The code I'm using is quite simple...
A very basic adapter

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/box"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#00ff00"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Press me"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/hidden_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

```
class TestAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>() {

    val items = arrayOf(false, false, false, false)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(
            ItemTestBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

     override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemBinding.hiddenView.isVisible = items[position]

        holder.itemBinding.button.setOnClickListener {
            items[position] = !items[position]
            notifyItemChanged(position)
        }

        return
    }
}

open class ViewHolder internal constructor(val itemBinding: ItemTestBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemBinding.root)
```

In a very basic layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:spanCount="2"
        tools:itemCount="4"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_test" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#ffff00"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/recycler"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.recycler.adapter = TestAdapter()
    }
}
```

I'm expecting to have the row shrink to the lower item

Please, note that when using a LinearLayout or a GridLayoutManager with a spanCount = 1, the behaviour is correct:

### [image: Start]

### [image: Press]

[image: Press again]

The problem seems to be related to this one:

[Items height in GridLayoutManager after dynamic action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66573880/items-height-in-gridlayoutmanager-after-dynamic-action) but that solution is not working here

This is a minimal project that replicates the problem:

https://mega.nz/file/R7IgmSwD#mwy28aMvMTagfkzSNjArIHANI5cUskG8vN7ZrVp-u94

Comment: That adapter (and the onClick in particular) is almost certainly incorrect.  Changing view visibility directly with no model change is pretty much never correct.  `onBindViewHolder` should recreate the view state entirely from the adapter's data.

Comment: @RyanM thanks for your note. That was due to an over simplification of the example; I updated it to reflect your pointing, but the problem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the hint of @RyanM and @Biscuit, I found a solution (or a workaround, I'm not sure about how to consider that).

When I update the item I do not just need to notify the recycler about the fact that I updated that single item, but also that all the items on the same row are updated: when an item is expanded, all the other items on the row change their height. So, calling

`notifyItemChanged(position)`

will make the layout manager recalculate that item height, but all the other items on the row will keep the "expanded" height, so the row won't shrink.

Calling

`notifyDataSetChanged()`

will force the GridLayoutManager to recalculate all the view sizes and will make the row shrink as expected.

This is the working code for onBindViewHolder

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.itemBinding.hiddenView.isVisible = items[position]

    holder.itemBinding.button.setOnClickListener {
        items[position] = !items[position]

        // Just a tiny optimization, that's needed only when shrinking
        if (!items[position])
            notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    return
}
```

Comment: You should avoid calling `notifyDataSetChanged` as this recalculate everything and can slow down your app

Answer (score 1):

```kotlin
class MyAdapter: ListAdapter<Int, MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>(MyDiffUtil) {
    private val openedView = mutableSetOf<Int>()

    private fun <E> MutableSet<E>.addOrRemove(item: E) {
        if(contains(item)) remove(item) else add(item)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        getItem(position)?.let {
            holder.bind(it, openedView.contains(it)) {
                openedView.addOrRemove(it)
                notifyItemChanged(position)
                if(position%2==0) {
                    notifyItemChanged(position+1)
                } else {
                    notifyItemChanged(position-1)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class MyViewHolder(private val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        private val mainText = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.main_text)
        private val mainButton = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.main_button)
        private val toggleView = view.findViewById<LinearLayoutCompat>(R.id.toggle_view)

        fun bind(number: Int, isOpen: Boolean, clickListener: () -> Unit) {
            mainText.text = "Hello World $number"
            mainButton.setOnClickListener { clickListener() }
            toggleView.isVisible = isOpen
        }
    }

    object MyDiffUtil: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Int>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Int, newItem: Int): Boolean = oldItem == newItem
        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Int, newItem: Int): Boolean = oldItem == newItem
    }
}
```

2 things to note:

1. The condition to display is wether the item is in the `openedView`
2. When the click happened you need to update both the item in the row which is the small calculation for 2 columns

If you have more columns you can just adapt it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I updated the code it to reflect your suggestion, but the problem remains.

Comment: You might want to change from `GridLayoutManager` to `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`

Comment: That has a complete different behaviour; I tried that, but when I expand an item, it moves all the others item between the columns. I just neet to properly resize the row :(

Comment: I've updated my code check it out

Comment: Yes, this should work, but it's taken as an assumption to know the number of columns. This can be passed as a parameter of the adapter, but it's breaking the separation between the adapter and the layoutManager. This is why I preferred to use notifyDataSetChanged() over multiple notifyItemChanged.
In my case I have a few items, so calling notifyDataSetChanged is not causing any performance problems. In similar situations with more items, where performance can be an issue, I agree that your multiple notifyItemChanged could perform better.

Comment: As aside note, I tried your code and it's causing a flicker.
Using your code and calling notifyDataSetChanged() instead twice notifyItemChanged works fine without flickering, even if I would have expected that your version works better. It could be related to the GridLayout implementation.

Comment: The flicker is actually the itemAnimator of the recyclerview because it's resubmitting the list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255745/discussion-between-p1x-and-biscuit).