# Android, How To Force RecyclerView to Layout Items?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

My RecyclerView takes a few seconds to load it's items. This is fine, but I want it to load its items before my RecyclerView is visible.

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36495009/force-recyclerview-to-redraw-its-items), but it isn't exactly what I'm looking for - I want my RecyclerView to call the Adapter's onCreateViewHolder() and onBindViewHolder() methods, again, BEFORE the RecyclerView is visible. Is this possibe?

Comment: If Recycerview working fine then Try to add progressbar for loading info to user

Answer (score 0):

your approach should be to
1.Show RecyclerView blank (nothing is visible) when UI is creating.

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(myLayoutManager);
recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter); // with no data
```

2. After Loading data into your data elements/holder to be shown in RecyclerView, just refresh RecyclerView

   myAdapter.setData(yourdata); // set data will be user defined method
   myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();